# How do I remove multiple similar unboxing warnings on Android Studio?

Tags: java, regex, android-studio, formatting

I have 200+ warnings on Android Studio from automatically generated code.

```
Unnecessary boxing 'Integer.valueOf(0)'
Remove boxing *Alt+Shift+Enter*
```

How do you get rid of these warning messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Replace in Path` dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

1. Check at `Regex` checkbox
2. Type `Integer.valueOf\(([0-9]+)\)` at the first input area
3. Type `$1` at the second input area
4. Click `REPLACE ALL`